# Getting Error 400: invalid_request while redirecting Authorization page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth

Following this guide (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc) I made the code work in localhost but it gives an **Error 400: invalid_request device_id and device_name are required for private IP: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/AuthCallback/IndexAsync** while redirecting to Authorization page. We added subdomain in dns for our windows server ip address and registered the same subdomain in google api console. Why google gets ip address of the server instead of subdomain? Is the problem related to dns?
These are the working codes on local machine:
HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (result.Credential != null)
        {
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                ApplicationName = "BPM Mail"
            });

            var gmailProfile = service.Users.GetProfile("me").Execute();
            var userGmailEmail = gmailProfile.EmailAddress;
            Utils.userMail = userGmailEmail;
            Utils.cred = result.Credential;

            
            // SAMPLE CODE:
            //var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
            //ViewBag.Message = "FILE COUNT IS: " + list.Items.Count();
            return new RedirectResult("~/Apps/Mail/Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
    
}
```

AppFlowMetadata.cs

```
public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
{
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "ClientId ",
                ClientSecret = "ClientSecret "
            },
            Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
            DataStore = new FileDataStore("D:/bpm_mail/mytokens/token.json", true)
        });

    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
        // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
        // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
        // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
        // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
        var user = controller.Session["user"];
        //Utils.userId = user.ToString();
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = Guid.NewGuid();
            controller.Session["user"] = user;
        }
        return user.ToString();

    }

    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }

    //public override string AuthCallback
    //{
    //    get { return @"/AuthCallback/IndexAsync"; }
    //}
}
```

AuthCallbackController.cs

```
public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
{
    protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
    {
        get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  And include the full error message that you are seeing.     As to why you are seeing a ip address its probably something in the settings for your app.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your suggestions. Can you tell me what's wrong with the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by changing private ip to public one and redirect it to domain.